# Two basic questions about icp (iterative closest point) algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, intuition, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to learn shape analysis and a part is learning icp. I have many confusions but for now I have two basic questions:

1. Does the point clouds need to have the same number of points for icp?
2. Does icp needs manual/automatic landmarking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't worked with ICP specifically I have done work with point clouds, hopefully you will get a better answer soon!

1. I don't think so. Consider a very simple example where you're just fitting a line to a pair of points. The (many) points on the line are each fit to the closest of the two points, and the the line is transformed to minimize this; this is repeated iteratively. (Note: the visual here is just a cartoon, I haven't done any computation to ensure this actually what a single step would look like)

[image]

2. The more distinct features you can landmark the better, weather it's manually or automatically. Automatic landmarking could be used (and if it works for your application that's great) but manual landmarking, especially if feature of both sets can be exactly match, is going to have a much better chance of forming a tight fit.

[image]

Comment: Hi Nate,

Thank you very much for the clear answers. They helped a lot.
About the second question, my main question is, is landmarking (regardless of being manually or automatic) essentially required in icp? In other words, is landmarking an inevitable step in the process of icp?

Comment: To be clear, by landmarking I assume you mean picking out specific points in the two shapes for comparison? That's going to depend a bit on how the data is stored and how the algorithm your using wants the data presented. In general I would think you don't need landmarking because almost all geometric data in computer is stored as a list of points, and these points can be used as the landmarks. But let me know if I have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: In some kind of alignments, some specific points should be selected 
(either manually or automatically) on the shapes so the alignment algorithm can do the alignment using the corresponding points. For example in face analyzing, the landmarks of the different faces are nose tip point, the point in the middle of two eyes, the bottom of the chin and so on. They are determined and labeled in all faces and then the alignment is done. My question is, is this step necessary in icp as well, or not. My assumption is it is not necessary, bot not sure.

Comment: I don't think it should be necessary. It might be helpful, but if you have 3D points clouds of faces already you should be able to register them without further keypointing.